# How to show No Data Available Message in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, no-data

Can we show a message using highcharts.When the data is not available? we have to show a message Example : `No Data Available`. If we have data hide : `No Data Available` message . in highcharts dynamically

```
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
     type: 'bubble',
     plotBorderWidth: 0,
     zoomType: 'xy'
   },
});
```

Comment: Well yes. Just don't create the highchart and insert text saying "No Data Available". Without any code, this is the most help you're likely to get.

Comment: See example...http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/no-data-to-display/no-data-pie/

Comment: can we increase font size and we need to must add no-data-to-display-js file

Comment: @Kondal Can I know what extra details you require from existing answer.

Comment: if we have  data still showing no data available message so,can  we hide in highcharts if we have data

Comment: check this [noData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/noData) from docs.This example works fine and tested. Add example where you fail

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Highcharts Chart Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer)

Here's an example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9ftbr0d/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: []

}, function(chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.text('No Data Available', 140, 120)
        .css({
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px'
        })
        .add();

});
```

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: How that text would be center alighned?

Answer (score 21):

Include no-data-to-display.js file in your page. It comes bundled with highcharts. You can get it here otherwise: https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js

Default message is "No data to display". If you would like to modify it, you can do this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        noData: 'Personalized no data message'
    }
});
```

Comment: Could we customize this message, like change color etc?

Comment: for me it is not working, the chart is empty and the message is not displayed either

Comment: Remeber to add <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>

Answer (score 14):

Some of these other answers seem kind of crazy... here's a super basic solution I wanted to share:

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({lang: {noData: "Your custom message"}})
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: []
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 250px"></div>
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: apart from live example how your post differs from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297065/8632727. It looks crazy

Answer (score 8):

Based on your comment (*if we have data still showing no data available message so,can we hide in highcharts if we have data*).I think you are using fustaki's solution and don't want to use **no-data-to-display.js** module. Yes there is problem as mentioned .You can still use the same code by modifying it i.e add condition inside continuing function to check if series is empty or not, based on this render message.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: []

}, function(chart) { // on complete
  if (chart.series.length < 1) { // check series is empty
    chart.renderer.text('No Data Available', 140, 120)
      .css({
        color: '#4572A7',
        fontSize: '16px'
      })
      .add();
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzjgxkyd/) demo

Answer (score 5):

For me with latest version it works like this:

```
const Highcharts = require('highcharts');

import NoDataToDisplay from 'highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display';
NoDataToDisplay(Highcharts);

Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    noData: 'No data is available in the chart'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With the current version (v7.1.2) and connected no-data-to-display module (v7.1.2) you can show your 'no data' message when you create a chart object as Patrik said by setting lang.noData option.

To be able to change this message after the chart is created you need to call method

```
yourChartObject.showNoData('you new message')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    lang: {
        noData: "No data found"
    },
    noData: {
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '15px'
        }
    },
    .
    .
});
```

Answer (score 0):

and then after series you should add:

```
 lang: {
    noData: 'Nessun dato presente'
 },
 noData: {
    style: {
         fontWeight: 'bold',
         fontSize: '15px',
         color: '#303030'
     }
},
```

and it will work just fine